# Confusion about "perfect match" and "matchb with minor adjustments" in the context of perfect forwarding ctor vs other constructors

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overload-resolution, perfect-forwarding

I was reading Chapter 25 from [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide - 2nd ed.](http://www.tmplbook.com/), where, given code more or less like this

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename...>
struct Tuple;

template<typename H, typename ...T>
struct Tuple<H, T...> {
    H h;
    Tuple<T...> t;
    Tuple() {}
    template<typename HH, typename ...TT>
    Tuple(HH&& h, TT&& ...t)
        : h{std::forward<HH>(h)}
        , t{std::forward<TT>(t)...} {}
    template<typename HH, typename ...TT>
    Tuple(Tuple<HH, TT...> const& other)
        : h{other.h}
        , t{other.t} {}
};

template<>
struct Tuple<> {};
```

and a `t` defined like this

```cpp
Tuple<int, double, std::string> const t;
```

the following definition fails

```
Tuple<long int, long double, std::string> t2{t};
```

Ok, good, I knew why that was happening and I started writing a margin note:

> The reason is that `t` is not `const`, which means that `template<typename HH, typename ...TT> Tuple(HH&&, TT&& ...)` is a perfect match for the call, whereas `template<typename HH, typename ...TT> Tuple(Tuple<HH, TT...> const&)` requies that `const` is added to the argument to match the parameter.

And I've verified it: if I make `t` `const`, then the definition of `t2` is fine an calls the correct ctor.

But then (assuming I don't add the `const` as per previous paragraph) I wondered "What type of match is the second, if the first is *perfect*?"

I was in double as to which of the several *non-perfect* matches that would be, so I moved forward to Appendix C, pages 682-683, Section C.2 to find out:

> 1. Perfect match. The parameter has the type of the expression, or it has a type that is a reference to the type of the expression (possibly with added `const` and/or `volatile` qualifiers).
> 2. Match with minor adjustments. This includes, for example, the dacy of an array variable to a pointer to its first element or the addition of `const` to match an argument of type `int**` to a parameter of type `int const* const*`

And now I'm a bit puzzled, because the ctor `template<typename HH, typename ...TT> Tuple(Tuple<HH, TT...> const& other)`, with reference to the definition of `t2`, has a parameter with type a reference to the type of the expression initializing it, because of template type deduction, with just an added `cosnt`. So isn't this exactly what a *perfect match* is, based on the excerpt from the book? Or am I misreading the book? Or my own code?

Comment: Book isn't standard so some statements might not be exactly precise. In your code you have a non-const object, hence it may be modified. So the function (ctor) which allows its modification is a better match than the `const&`: you need to add `const` in one case but nothing in the other. I think the book is a little bit "greedy" in its first point—it tries to eat the second point as well.

Comment: For a more precise discussion, see [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and [Ranking of implicit conversion sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences). In particular, adding `const` is known as a qualification conversion.